# Can't convert a date with timezone to a customized one

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert dates from `2016-04-30T00:00:00Z` to `2016-04-30`. I get success from the first two. However, in case of the last one,I get `ValueError: time data '2021-12-31T15:28:43.040Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`. How can I fix it?

I've tried with:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_list = [
    '2016-04-30T00:00:00Z',
    '2007-10-31T00:00:00Z',
    '2021-12-31T15:28:43.040Z'
]

for raw_date in date_list:
    _date = datetime.strptime(raw_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(_date)
```

Comment: If the dates are consistent, just use `raw_date[:10]`

Comment: '2021-12-31T15:28:43.040Z' would be '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the library called `pandas`, it would be much easier:

```
from pandas import to_datetime
date_list = [
    '2016-04-30T00:00:00Z',
    '2007-10-31T00:00:00Z',
    '2021-12-31T15:28:43.040Z'
]
print(to_datetime(date_list).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

If you don't have that library, try this:

```
date_list = [
    '2016-04-30T00:00:00Z',
    '2007-10-31T00:00:00Z',
    '2021-12-31T15:28:43.040Z'
]

for raw_date in date_list:
    _date = raw_date.split('T')[0]
    print(_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix, i will do this.

```py
for raw_date in date_list:
    _date = datetime.strptime(raw_date.split('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(_date)
```

or

```py
for raw_date in date_list:
    _date = raw_date.split('T')[0]
    print(_date)
```